# Control key not working after Qlipper configuration

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, lubuntu, ctrl

My question looks a lot like this one : [My control key doesn't work, how do I fix it?](https://superuser.com/questions/88835/my-control-key-doesnt-work-how-do-i-fix-it) but I think the context is different because the solutions given do not work for me.

#### Context

I have a Linux VM with the distribution Lubuntu 20.04

Today, I tried to configure the shortcut of my Qlipper installed by default:
[Qlipper config image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezRcw.jpg)

I wanted to set it to "CTRL + ù" but right after I changed it, my CTRL key stopped responding the way it used to. It is now impossible to execute any kind of shortcut involving the left CTRL key (which means CTRL+A, CTRL-V, and the most annoying: CTRL-C in a terminal to kill a process...)

#### Steps tried

- I went in the terminal and ran `xmodmap -pke` and Control_L is correctly set, at keycode 37:

> `keycode  37 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L`

- I tried the solution given in the other topic, which is : exporting into a file the result of xmodmap -pke and add two lines at the bottom (clear Control and add Control = Control_L Control_R) and run xmodmap on this edited file but it didn't work
- I took the globalkeyboardshortcuts.conf file of another environment running Lubuntu 20.04 and switched it with the one I have in this one, but it did not work either

I have no idea what to try next. Does anybody have a suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it seemed that Qlipper was the cause of my problems. I went on to configure Qlipper once again and decided to remove the shortcut I added previously, which was `CTRL + ù`. After I saved, my CTRL key was functional again.

Really strange behavior that caused me headaches for a few hours. Hope this helps someone someday